# Simple? Post Jquery Array to rails controller#action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, post

Cannot seems to figure out how I can post a query(json) array to a rails controller#action

I have just like

```
var myarray = []; ( with values )
```

My controller action I want to post to:

```
def process
end
```

Everywhere I find answers on how to get JSON -> Jquery 
But Ill need the other way around. Anyone knows how to do this? Can't be that hard?!

Comment: Do you want to `post` (screen flash, reloads page) or `AJAX Post` in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a few ways to do this, but here's one.  Use some JS like this to post to your controller:

```
var target = "your-action-url";
var myarray = [1,2,3,etc];
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: target + '?order='+myarray.join(',') ,
    dataType: 'script'
});
```

Then, in your controller:

```
data = params[:order].split(',')
```

Now you have an array that matches what you had in javascript.

Comment: You could easily run into problems with large arrays, since URLs have a character limit

Comment: I only post integers and no more than 20 so that will work out, something to look into later on ( if anyone has suggestion to fix that its more then welcome ). Had some 500 server error cause I forgot to create the view file! all seems to work great now thx!

Comment: you could always POST instead of GET to take care of the URL size issue.  I haven't actually hit the URL character limit issue in over a decade personally, although it is worth being aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery documentation has information about posting: [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Does something like this help?
`$.post('path-to-process-action', {myarray: myarray}`)

Comment: This is good, but you instead of just passing the array as the data argument you should use a map like `$.post('path-to-process-action', {myarray: myarray})`

Comment: Edited answer to use the map version